# How to shuffle rows in an array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, processing, shuffle

I'm trying to shuffle the rows in my current array in Processing. This array contains 24 rows and is a two-dimensional-array. Can someone tell me what I do wrong?

```java
float[][] shuffleArray(float[][] myArray) {   
  float[][] newArray = myArray;   
  int random1 = round(random(0, 24));
  int random2 = round(random(0, 24));
  float[] buffer1 = newArray[random1];
  float[] buffer2 = newArray[random2];
  newArray[random2] = buffer1;
  newArray[random1] = buffer2;   
  return newArray; 
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to tell us your programming language?

Comment: java in processing

Comment: @Dave The phrase "java in processing" is somewhat ambiguous. Processing *is* a programming language in its own right (albeit one which is based on Java and runs on the JVM) but it isn't Java. I *think* your question is about Processing instead of Java, in which case your mention of Java just muddies the question.

Comment: It also isn't clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to return a new array or are you trying to modify the passed array? Your use of `return` suggests the former, but you seem to be flirting with code that will modify the passed array as a side effect. Also, you said `24` elements but also "multidimensional". A single number doesn't adequately nail it down. Is 24 = 12 x 2? 4 x 6? Please clarify.

Comment: i'm trying to modify the order of the past array into a new array. the current array is myArray[24][3].

Comment: Are you trying to shuffle the 24 rows, treating each row (perhaps thought of as a point in 3-dimensional space) as a unit? Or -- are you trying to freely shuffle the 24x3 = 72 elements so that rows are broken up?

Comment: I'm trying to shuffle the 24 rows as a unit. sorry for the bad explanation, my English is not that good.

Comment: You need to [debug your program](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) by tracing through the code with a piece of paper and a pencil, or the debugger that comes with the Processing editor, until you understand where your code's execution differs from what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem, you first have to [debug your program](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to figure out exactly what your program does.

The best thing to do is to go through your code line by line to understand what's happening.

```java
float[][] shuffleArray(float[][] myArray) {   
  float[][] newArray = myArray;   
  int random1 = round(random(0, 24));
  int random2 = round(random(0, 24));
  float[] buffer1 = newArray[random1];
  float[] buffer2 = newArray[random2];
  newArray[random2] = buffer1;
  newArray[random1] = buffer2;   
  return newArray; 
}
```

- First, you point a `newArray` variable to the `myArray` variable. Note that this means that both variables point to the same array, so changes to one will affect the other.
- Then you create two random numbers, but note that those random numbers might be the same.
- Then you get the sub-array at those indexes, which again might be the same. Then you swap the sub-arrays.
- Then you return `newArray`, but remember that this is pointing to the same array that `myArray` is. So you're just modifying the input array and then returning a reference to it.

So, what this function does is **maybe** swap two sub-arrays in your 2D array. This is not the same as shuffling the whole array. Picture taking a deck of cards and maybe swapping two of the cards. That's not the same thing as shuffling the whole deck.

To understand references, I recommend you read [this](https://javaranch.com/campfire/StoryCups.jsp) and then [this](https://javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp).

Now, to fix your problem, Google is your friend. Searching for "java shuffle array" will return a ton of results, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470094/how-to-shuffle-an-array). If you have problems in the future, please try to work through this process of debugging your program so you understand exactly what your code is doing before you ask a question. Good luck.