# Java How do I shuffle the rows of a 2D array?

Tags: java

I have written some code that reads a CSV file and does some data preprocessing and then it's supposed to shuffle the rows of the 2D array not the columns though the order of that can't change.

The issue I am having is that it does shuffle the rows and the columns of the 2D array and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

public class RandomForest
{
  public static void shuffle2DArray()
    {
        int numRows = allFeatures.length;
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();

        // Populate the list with indices
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            indices.add(i);
        }

        // Shuffle the list of indices
        Collections.shuffle(indices);

        // Create a copy of the original array
        int[][] shuffledArray = new int[numRows][allFeatures[0].length];

        // Use shuffled indices to rearrange the rows of the original array
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            shuffledArray[i] = allFeatures[indices.get(i)];
        }

        // Update the original array with the shuffled values
        allFeatures = shuffledArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        RandomForest rf = new RandomForest("SE-Dermatitis Dataset.csv");

        rf.getDataRows();
        rf.markFilters();
        rf.removeAttributes();

        int count = 1;
        int counter = 1;

        int totalPredAcc = 0;

        int allFeaturesSize = allFeatures.length;
        int foldSize = allFeaturesSize / 10;

        Double[] threshold = {0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7};

        shuffle2DArray();
    }
}
```

There are other methods as you can see but they work fine just this shuffle2DArray() method.

This is so I can randomly divide the data into 10 folds so that I can do 10-fold cross-validation

I did try putting print statements in the code and try checking the 2D array before and after trying to shuffle and then checking the CSV file to make sure the order of that row is correct.

This is small example of what it looks like before filtering:

| cpi_9606.ENSP00000000233 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000000412 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000000442 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000001008 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000001146 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000002165 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000002829 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000003084 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000003100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 180 |

After Filtering  and shuffling columns:

| cpi_9606.ENSP00000000442 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000001008 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000003084 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000003100 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000005178 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000011292 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000011653 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000012443 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000013034 | cpi_9606.ENSP00000014930 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 900 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 900 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 900 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 928 | 900 | 338 |  |
| 322 | 236 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |

Comment: Shuffling the rows of a 2D array is really just shuffling a regular 1-dimensions array (where each item in the array just happens to be another array). You can find a number of solutions to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array) (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470094/how-to-shuffle-an-array)).

Comment: running your sample shuffle2DArray(), I am thinking that the shuffle of the data may be correct, but looking at your edits are you also shuffling the column headers at the same time? this may be what is causing it to look wrong?

Comment: Your example makes no sense. The 'before filtering' data looks _nothing_ like 'after'. It's not even a shuffle, it's just flat out different data.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet fails to include the key element: The array you wanna sort.

So, taking a wild stab in the dark, I guess it looks like this:

```
int[][] allFeatures = ....;
```

To shuffle it, it's a one liner. You can ditch all the code you have:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(allFeatures));
```

So, why does this work?

**Because there is no such thing as a 2D array. Java simply does not have them.**

That `int[][] allFeatures` you have is not a 2D array. It's a 1D array whose component types are int arrays. Therefore, `Arrays.asList(allFeatures)` is perfectly fine, given that you have an array of objects (not primitives) - each object being an int array. That expression is typed `List<int[]>`.

`Arrays.asList` returns a list that remains backed by the underlying array. Hence, `.set()` works, but `.add()` does not (as arrays can change their elements but cannot grow or shrink). `Collections.shuffle` can shuffle any list, and only uses `.set` and `.get` to do so: Operations that `Arrays.asList` supports just fine.

The upshot of it all is that this will shuffle `allFeatures` itself.

If you want to keep `allFeatures` unchanged, make a clone first:

```
int[][] clone = allFeatures.clone();
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(clone));
```

Comment: yes you are correct apologies forgot to add that one here it is:

private static int[][] allFeatures;

Comment: I have just tried implementing that change and it does seem to changing the order of the columns as they don't match up to the original csv. I have also had the 2D array before shuffle get written a file to make sure that is correctly ordered and it is. Any reasons why this might be.

Comment: @Elmo can you show sample of the code output and what is the correct output you expect?

Comment: Basically once I have done some filtering of the columns which is were I looked at each column and check and see how many occurrences are above 0.5 (the data is numeric format but I do a calculation) the dataset should have a lot less columns

Comment: It difficult to show with the filtering and the shuffling but say if I check the 442 cpi column for a value after it is shuffled and then check to see in the original dataset it is in the right place it isn't for some reason even though before shuffling it was fine

Comment: @Elmo thanks for taking the trouble to attempt showing the output, if it is possible try to put it inside the question instead of the comments since you can better apply formatting there.

Comment: It sounds like you want to shuffle the columns and not the rows. Transpose the array (generally, just read it 'in the other direction').

Comment: @rzwitserloot no I don't want to shuffle the columns they need to be in order as I have saved columns that are staying in the same order. As I am going to create an arff file for weka

Comment: @BIBOOunit1998X I have edited the question hope that makes more sense now